# Integration test for component containing a component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

I have a component that uses another component. But it doesn't work because the test for the first component says it's missing a `helper` called `curit-select`.

In `0.10` you could add a `needs to the`moduleForComponent` function but doing that now will force it to unit-testing mode. ([see](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit#component-integration-tests))

> You do not require dependencies through needs:. Doing so will force the test into unit mode.

component 1:

```
<div class='change-device-status'>
  Status: {{curit-select content=statuses selection=device.status}}
  <button class="save-button" {{action 'save'}}>opslaan</button>
</div>
```

component 2:

```
<select {{action 'change' on='change'}}>
  {{#if prompt}}
    <option disabled selected={{is-not selection}}>
      {{prompt}}
    </option>
  {{/if}}

  {{#each content key="@identity" as |item|}}
    <option value="{{read-path item optionValuePath}}"
            selected={{is-equal item selection}}>
      {{read-path item optionLabelPath}}
     </option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Now I'm trying to write an integration test for the first component:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('change-device-status', 'Integration | Component | change device status', {
  integration: true
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(3);

  // Set any properties with this.set('myProperty', 'value');
  // Handle any actions with this.on('myAction', function(val) { ... });

  this.set('dev', {
    status: 'InUse'
  });

  this.render(hbs`{{change-device-status content=dev}}`);

  assert.equals(this.$().text().trim(), '');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll just work! Remember restart `ember serve`.

Comment: ?? It'll just work? I'm facing this problem right now.. Restarting `ember serve` doesn't do anything.. that's what livereload is for?

Comment: Sometimes when you add and change a lot of things the autoreload won't pickup all the changes. Then you have to restart `ember serve`. When I had this issue restarting it helped. There's no real reason this won't work.

Comment: For those cruising here from the Googles: He's right. If you're facing an issue here, something else is wrong. IT JUST WORKS. TRUST THAT IT JUST WORKS :D

I pained over what I was doing wrong in my tests for hours before I realized I was making a stupid mistake in my component (not the test) and I was assuming the error was coming from testing incorrectly.

The comment about restarting `ember serve` doesn't specifically apply here, but it is useful, it just happens to work sometimes when you're seeing inconsistencies between what you're expecting to happen and what's happening.